# RegExr out of range for backslash in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i got out of range error  for using \ (bakcslash) for regExr Match.. ..solution please.....!!

```
 if ($('.channelquickvalidte').val().match("^[a-zA-Z\s0-9, '@+&$,._!#%^*()_+=/<>\\]+$") == null)  /* Error... */

{ alert("Character between A-Z/a-z and 0-9 are allowed. Additional you can use \"''@+&,._$!#%^*()_+=<>/\\\" character"); // its working fine
```

Error::

```
SyntaxError: invalid range in character class
(5525 out of range 177)
```

Comment: Why bother having `\s` inside your character class if you also have ` ` in it? Try removing `\s` or move it to another position. I could imagine, that js interprets `\s0` in some weird way which yields the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the backslash at the end of the char class, use:

```
match("^[a-zA-Z\s0-9, '@+&$,._!#%^*()_+=/\\<>]+$")
```

or

```
match("^[a-zA-Z\s0-9, '@+&$,._!#%^*()_+=/<>\\\\]+$")
```

You can reduce it to:

```
match("^[\w\s,'@+&$,.!#%^*()+=/\\<>]+$")
```

`\w` usualy stands for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` but it depends on locale.
`\s` stands for any space character ie. `[ \t\r\n\f]`, so you don't need an additional space within the car class